# How to show and search in google autocomplete just place my current city(area)?

Tags: ios, google-maps, autocomplete, mapkit

There are problems with auto complete, to me google autocomplete `search bar` is filling writes all cities in the world but I need only the address of my city.

Comment: Add please more about your problem. What have you tried already. Some piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [GMSCoordinateBounds](https://developers.google.com/places/ios/autocomplete#get-predictions), which is

> A object which restrict the results to a specific area specified by latitude and longitude bounds.

In additional, There are some [Location Biasing](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/autocomplete#location_biasing) options for the JS API, but no sure if iOS API has them too.

Answer (score 0):

I found information, we cant search just in city.We can minimum set search in Country. Google say -  they will fix it in next version.

```
NSMutableString *url = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=%@&sensor=%@&components=country:%@""&key=%@",
                                                         [input stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],
                                                         SPBooleanStringForBool(sensor), countryCode,key];
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
GMSVisibleRegion visibleRegion = self.mapView.projection.visibleRegion;
GMSCoordinateBounds *bounds = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc] initWithCoordinate:visibleRegion.farLeft coordinate:visibleRegion.nearRight];
```